# PyQGIS 3.18.2 Removing Band Name from Symbology

Tags: gdal, qgis, pyqgis

I recently updated my QGIS and I noticed the styles now show the band `Band 1(Gray)`
[image]
[image]

The issue is it now shows within my print layout:
[image]

Using PYQGIS, how can I remove *just* the `Band 1 (Gray)`?

For reference, here is how I am currently setting the legend in the layout:

```
def set_legend(layout: QgsPrintLayout, tree: QgsLayerTree, layer: QgsLayer, item_id: str):
  '''Sets the Legend items'''
  logging.info(f'setting legend: {item_id}')
  item = layout.itemById(item_id)

  # set layer as root for legend
  tree.addLayer(layer)
  item.model().setRootGroup(tree)
  node = item.model().rootGroup().findLayer(layer)
  
  # hide the node title
  QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(node, QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution after digging StackOverflow and the API:

```
root = model.rootGroup().findLayer(layer)

# hide the node with label: Band 1 (Gray)
if isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer):
  nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(root)
  if nodes[0].data(0) == 'Band 1 (Gray)':
    indexes = list(range(1, len(nodes)))
    QgsMapLayerLegendUtils.setLegendNodeOrder(root, indexes)
    model.refreshLayerLegend(root)
```